# Multivariate Linear Function

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, multilinear-algebra

Linear Definition is as follows 
$$L(x + y )= L(x) + L(y) $$ 
$$L(ax) = aL(x)$$

I get confused with the definition for multivariate linear function.
Let's say we have a function like below.
$$L(x, y)= x^2 + yx^3$$ Can I say this function is linear **with respect to $y$**?
If so, how the definition for linear function is used here, and or not why this is not a linear function with respect to $y$?

(If you give me a useful link for this, then I really appreciate it.)

Comment: For the function to be linear, it has to satisfy $L(\vec{u}+ \vec{v}) = L(\vec{u}) + L(\vec{v})$ and $L(\lambda \vec{v}) = \lambda L(\vec{v})$ for all **vectors** $\vec{u}, \vec{v}$ and all scalars $\lambda$. You could have a notion of "linearity with respect to a variable", but that's not the given definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not what the linearity means. First, you can't say that your function is linear with respect to $y$ because $$L(x, \lambda y) = x^2 + \lambda yx^3 \neq \lambda (x^2 + y x^3) = \lambda L(x,y),$$ which is to say it fails one of the conditions.

In your case, linearity means that for all $(x_1, y_1)$, $(x_2,y_2)$ you have $$L(x_1+x_2, y_1+y_2) = L(x_1,y_1) + L(x_2,y_2).$$ In other words, you take the sum of the components to the sum of the images for all coordinates, not just one of them.

Multiplication by a scalar, which is your second condition, means that you'd have to multiply both $x$ and $y$, that is, $$L(\lambda x, \lambda y) = \lambda L(x,y).$$ [Wikipedia has a nice set of examples, in particular, the last one with gifs.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_map#Examples)